# how to access ui object from another class in QT

Tags: qt

I have created one UI file  wth some widgets in QT designer

```
'testScreen.ui'
'testScreen.cpp'
'testScreen.h'
```

now I am creating object of TestScreen class in another ccp file 'sstApplication.cpp'

```
TestScreen *obj =  new TestScreen()
```

now when I am try to access the widgets of testScreen.ui'

```
this->ui->next_But->setEnabled(true);
```

i am unable to do it

Answer (score 3):

When using QtDesigner, subwidgets are incapsulated into the generated Ui class. You have two ways to use it:

1) Write a getter for the ui class. This is a bad method because it violates incapsulation:

```
public:
    Ui::TestScreen *ui() const { return ui; }
```

and access it from your sstApplication.cpp:

```
TestScreen *obj =  new TestScreen()
obj->ui()->next_But->setEnabled(true);
```

2) Make a setter for next button state:

```
public:
    void enableNextButton(bool enabled = true) { this->ui->next_But->setEnabled(enabled); }
```

and use it like this:

```
obj->enableNextButton();
```

However, the best solution would be to incapsulate widget state management logic into `TestScreen`

Comment: thanks dwrd for the reply.......what do you mean by ' incapsilate widget state management logic into TestScreen'

Comment: I mean that you must not mix view and logic. It would be better to have something like model class and to handle to its state modification with triggering button enabled state